# How to set form variable in ASP.NET web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, forms, http

I am creating a web page that can redirect a SAMLResponse (as well as other attributes) from SiteMinder to a client's Identity Server. I am able to set form variables in the front end like this:

```
<asp:hiddenfield id="SAMLResponse" runat="server" ></asp:hiddenfield>
```

In the backend, I am parsing the SAML value from the Request InputStream like below:

```
private string RequestBody()
{
     var bodyStream = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
     bodyStream.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     string bodyText = bodyStream.ReadToEnd();
     return bodyText.Substring(bodyText.IndexOf("=") + 1);
}
```

With some logging statements, I can see that I am successfully parsing the SAMLResponse value, but when I am passing saml_response value to the web form via asp:hiddenfield or document.getElementById, the value comes up as blank. however, hardcoding a value works. Here is what it looks like when I pass the value to the hiddenfield/form element from the backend:

```
saml_response = RequestBody();
SAMLResponse.Value = saml_response;
```

I have tried the above approach, and the approach below (frontend) and both have worked for hardcoding, but not when trying to pass the parsed SAML response:

```
var samlresponse = "<%=saml_response%>";
document.getElementById("SAMLResponse").Value = samlresponse;
```

I am drawing a blank, and have been stuck on this all day! Any suggestions on why this is not working, or on how I should proceed? I thought it may have something to do with processes running asynchronously and overwriting the variable values, but I can't be sure.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:
I figured out that SiteMinder is sending the first requests, a POST (with the SAML) and then the something else is triggering a GET. The second request is triggering my backend code again and overwriting the SAMLResponse. Is there any way to persist the original value despite this being a different request?**

Comment: Give an example of the value you are trying to set. Post the code where you are trying to set the hiddenfield.

Comment: Added more details. SAML values are just encoded text around 4000 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your codebehind to pass the value to a javascript function that sets the hiddenfield.

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, typeof(string), "SetResponse", "SetResponse('" + saml_response + "');", true);
```

Javascript :

```
 function SetResponse(Res) {

            var data = Res;

            $(function () {
              $('#SAMLResponse').val(data);
                          });


        }
```

add the jQuery library right before your script starts

```
<script src="../jquery/jquery-1.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also go ahead and set an alert in that function alert("works yo");
We need to make sure the script is not breaking before it executes that function.

Comment: So this works similar to the other methods I have tried. I figured out that SiteMinder is sending the first requests, a POST (with the SAML) and then the something else is triggering a GET. The second request is triggering my backend code again and overwriting the SAMLResponse. Is there any way to persist the original value despite this being a different request?

Comment: errr... can you only write to the hiddenfield if its a POST & ignore the GET?  if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
{
    // The action is a POST.
}

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comments! I was able to resolve the issue by preventing the second call. The issue was that with the second call, the form value was being overridden.